# Getting an option element's value in java

Tags: java, javascript

I am extremely new to javascript and I have worked on this for hours.... Figured I'd ask some experts.

I am setting the value of an option element in this javascript function:

```
function receiveAnswer(response) {
  var aSeats = document.getElementById("aSeats");
    aSeats.options.length = 0;// clear it out

   for (var i = 0; i < response.aSeats.length; i++) { // add the items back in
    var option = aSeats.appendChild(document.createElement("option"));
    option.value = i;
    option.appendChild(document.createTextNode(response.aSeats[i]));
  }
}
```

Here is the html:

```
<% Venue v = (Venue)session.getAttribute("currentVenue"); %>
<% List<Conceptual_Package> cpList = Conceptual_PackageDAO.getInstance().getByVenue(v.getId()); %>

What Packages do you want to see?

 <form method="post" action="ttp.actions.Sale3PackAction.action">
 <select name="packid" id="packid">
     <% for (Conceptual_Package cp: cpList) { %>
    <option value="<%=cp.getId()%>"><%=cp.getName1()%></option>
    <% } %>


 </select>

    <input type="button" value="  next  " onclick="getSeats();"/>

    </form>


<!--new-->


Available Seats:

<div>

</div>

 <select name="aSeats" size="10" id="aSeats">
 </select>


    <input type="button" value="  add  " onclick="addToCart();"/>

    <div>

    </div>


Selected Seats:
 <form method="post" action="ttp.actions.sale4Action.action">
     <select name="Seat2" size="10" id="seat2">

     </select>

<input type="button" value="  remove  " onclick="removeFromCart();"/>

    </form>

<div>

</div>

 <form method="post" action="ttp.actions.finalizeSaleAction.action">

    <input type="submit" value="  Buy Tickets  "/>

    </form>
```

I want to get the value of those option elements in this java class:

```
public class finalizeSaleAction implements Action {
    public String process(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        Venue v = (Venue) session.getAttribute("currentvenue");
        Sale s = SaleDAO.getInstance().create(GUID.generate());
        if(session.getAttribute("type") == "packages"){


            Conceptual_Package cp = (Conceptual_Package) request.getAttribute("cp");

            List<Physical_Package> ppList = (List<Physical_Package>) request.getAttribute("seat2");

            Physical_Pkg_Set pps = Physical_Pkg_SetDAO.getInstance().create(GUID.generate());

            pps.setType("Phys Package Set");
            pps.setDiscount(cp.getDiscount());
            pps.setVenueID(v.getId());

            double price = 0;

            Object seatList = request.getAttribute("seat2");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the name of the option element.  When the form is submitted the browser will send `name=value` in the query or post data.

From your servlet code, you can get the value for that form element with:

```
request.getParameter(name);
```

You may see an IE bug that makes this complicated.  See:

http://easy-reader.net/archives/2005/09/02/death-to-bad-dom-implementations/

edit:

If I understand you correctly, your form (which you would build with JS or maybe server-side) might look something like:

```
<html>
 <body>
  <form action="blah" method="post">
   <table>
    <tr><td>Pink Unicorn</td><td>14.95</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Sparkly Vampire</td><td>12.99</td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="do it now" /></td></tr>
   </table>
   <input type="hidden" name="item1" value="PU1" />
   <input type="hidden" name="item2" value="SV1" />
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Note that the `<td>`s are visible in the browser, while the `<input>`s are not.  The post data from this request would look like:

```
item1=PU1&item2=SV1
```

Comment: @Tim Sylvester Sorry I don't think I explained myself well. I need to get every option element out of this select element: ``<select name="Seat2" size="10" id="seat2">`` (see edits above) so I'm wondering how I get all of those options and then get the value of each of them....

Comment: You want *all* the option values server-side?  The browser only sends the selection option value, so the rest aren't available.  You could send them as other input elements in the form with `<input type="hidden"`.

Comment: Yeah I think that's what I need to do. How do I put that into the form??

Comment: Actually I don't think that will work. The select elements that I'm working with are like a shopping cart type system. So people add items to the select element and then I need to take all of those added items and build the objects out of the value that is in them. any good ideas. I'm out of them haha

Comment: Should be possible, use JS to create hidden form inputs for everything you want to send.  Call them 'item1' ... 'itemN' or something.

Comment: Do you not care which one is selected then?  Maybe a `<select>` isn't the right control anyway...

Comment: Yeah I guess I don't need it to be a select because I want all of the items every time. What type would you suggest?

Comment: If you want to submit many values in a form your only options are many input elements or a single one with all the values concatenated into it.  The former is better in every respect.  Keep in mind that what the user sees and what the form submits don't have to be the same or even related.  You can have plain old HTML, like `<span>`s or something that display the items in the "cart", and a bunch of hidden input elements that specify actual the form data.  I'll update my answer...

Comment: that looks more like what I need to do. I'll try it out and let you know...THanks soooooo much for taking the time to help a novice like me

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
request.getAttribute("seat2");
```

use

```
request.getParameter("seat2");
```

And to get all the values of the  **selected** option elements from browser.

Change the following select tag  to

```
 <select name="aSeats" size="10" id="aSeats"  multiple="multiple"/>
```

this way , you can select multiple options values in the browser .And in the server side , you can retreive the values of the selected options like below

```
String[] selectedSeats = request.getParameterValues("seat2");
```

**To get all the values of select options  do the following using jQuery**

```
 <input type ="hidden" name ="selectedSeats" id ="selectedSeats" value=""/>

 var optionValues= new Array();
 $("#aSeats").each(function()
 {
     optionValues.push($(this).val()); 
 });

 var selectedValues = optionValues.get().join(',');
 $('#selectedSeats').val(selectedValues);
```

From the server side you use.

```
String seats= request.getParameter("selectedSeats");
String selectedSeats[] = seats.split(",");
```